# ASP.NET/sql full text search

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq

I am using the below query for fulltext searh for sql server.

```
    DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (Id int identity(1,1), Searched varchar(200))
DECLARE @Keys    TABLE (Word varchar(200), WordId int identity(1,1))

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('Mother Father Daughter Son')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('Mother Daughter Son')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('Mother Son')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('Daughter Son')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('Mother Father Son')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('Son Daughter Father')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('Mother bun')
INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES ('Other Word')


INSERT INTO @Keys VALUES ('Mother')
INSERT INTO @Keys VALUES ('Father')
INSERT INTO @Keys VALUES ('Son')
INSERT INTO @Keys VALUES ('Daughter')

DECLARE @nAllWords int
SELECT @nAllWords = COUNT(*) FROM @Keys

SELECT MyTable.*
FROM @MyTable MyTable
INNER JOIN (SELECT MyTable.Id
                   FROM @MyTable MyTable
            INNER JOIN @Keys KeyWords ON ' ' + MyTable.Searched + ' ' LIKE '% ' + KeyWords.Word  + ' %'
            GROUP BY MyTable.Id
            HAVING COUNT(Distinct(KeyWords.Word)) = @nAllWords) Tbl1 ON MyTable.Id = Tbl1.Id
```

But the above code return only single records which is below one.

```
Mother Father Daughter Son
```

i need result like full 4 words(Mother Father Daughter Son),next any 3 words(Mother Daughter Son),next any 2 and next 1
so my results like

```
Mother Father Daughter Son
Mother Daughter Son
Mother Father Son
      :
      :

Mother bun
```

please advice me on this for multiple columns ,i am trying with one column now.Once i get this next i'll try with multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the below code from the query, it will give the desired result!

```
HAVING COUNT(Distinct(KeyWords.Word)) = @nAllWords
```